# Generated code is leading to a sass compound selector error

Tags: sass, gulp, netsuite, gulp-sass

I'm currently working on a netsuite suite commerce site to migrate to google 4 analytics.

I am at the stage of deploying the changes to netsuite which uses a gulp project and generates a DeployDistribution. However this deploy distribution then has code which throws the following error.

[17:23:44] stack Error: compound selectors may no longer be extended.
Consider `@extend .button-secondary, :hover` instead.
See https://sass-lang.com/d/extend-compound for details.
422 │     @extend .button-secondary:hover;

I have attempted to downgrade to a version of sass that didn't have this depreciation but that didn't work.

I have attempted to alter the code manually after generation but the process just regenerates the code every time.

I'm not sure how to proceed.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The resolve to this was to change to WSL and use node-sass.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).